# How to capture timings for spring cloud stream composite functions

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

I have a spring cloud stream app chaining together some functions.  I need a nice way to log time taken for each function without having to wrap the logic for each in log and timing statements.  I can do it if I write the function as an anonymous inner class and annotate the apply method but its a bit ugly

spring:
cloud:
function:
definition: f1|f2|f3

```
@Bean
public Function<Message<String>, Message<String>> f1(){
  return f -> {
        do stuff
         return f;
    };
 }

public Function<Message<String>, Message<String>> f1(){
  return new Function<Message<String>, Message<String>>(){
    @LogTiming(name = f1)
    public Message<String> apply(Message<String> msg){  

 }
```

Any tips/examples would be great

Comment: Hi & Welcome! [Spring-cloud-sleuth](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#getting-started) sounds like matching your needs: "Spring Cloud Sleuth provides API for distributed tracing solution for Spring Cloud." ..."Span: The basic unit of work. ...Spans can be started and stopped, and they keep track of their timing information. Once you create a span, you must stop it at some point in the future."

Comment: I tested this, it will give you the time for f1|f2|f3 but not the individual functions.
I managed to get it to log time taken using Aop @Around("bean(f1)") however, it involved knowing the names of the beans